# Configuration error: System.Web.Helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0, web-config, iis-6

I deployed a site to a server and I get this error.  Why do I get this?

```
Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 


Line 16:       <assemblies>
Line 17:         <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
Line 18:         <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
Line 19:         <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
Line 20:         <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

Source File: C:\<path>\web.config Line: 18 

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Looks like the server on which you deployed the application doesn't have ASP.NET MVC 3 installed. If you do not want to install ASP.NET MVC 3 on the server you could also [bin deploy](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx) your application.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and i installed ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update from Microsoft site and it resolved the problem.

Also check if the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET is present prior to installation. As in my case this folder was missing and post installation i has this folder and assemblies got registered.

Answer (score 0):

I had the following situation. A brand new laptop with Visual Studio 2015 working on a somewhat older MVC3 project. Visual Studio 2015 and later does apparently no longer install MVC 3. So after downloading the AspNetMVC3ToolsUpdateSetup.exe and installing it, the right references where found (from GAC). And the build completed with no errors, no extra steps needed besides this install.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments in [Phil Haack's bin deploy post](https://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx/) recent versions of Visual Studio don't have right-click `Add Deployable Dependencies` option on projects so you can do this:

> Use the Package Manager Console and run the following command:
>
> `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 3.0.20105.1`
>
> That should reference all the assemblies in a manner that will make it
>   bin deployable.

I then got this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'NuGet.Core, Version=1.0.11220.104,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies.

Which I got rid of by deleting the file: `bin\System.Web.WebPages.Administration.dll`